# How do i store and retrieve images from browser cache storage and set them as background in react app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api, google-chrome-extension

I am building a new tab extension that displays an image to the user whenever a new tab is opened , I am using a third party API for fetching, the problem is that for every re-render the images are being download all over again , thus making the app look glitchy, how can i store images in local storage so whenever the user opens a new tab the image is displayed instantly ?

Comment: You can download images using `fetch` and store inside IndexedDB as ArrayBuffer or as a dataURI in localStorage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.